# CSS Help - Remove blank space between Images (<img>)

Tags: css, reactjs

Right now I am trying to make images stack side by side, vertically and horizontally, so that there is no white spaces between them. This is what my view currently looks like.

[image]

Ideally, there would be none of that blank, white space. I have inserted the ReactJS code below with my GifViewer component that holds the . Any ideas on how I can get this to work? And the code will not run due to the axios request, so it's just for visual effect right now.

```css
img {
 display: inline !important;
 width: 20%;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: auto;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

class GifViewer extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <img
    key={this.props.keyyer}
    src={`https://i.giphy.com/${this.props.id}.gif`}
   />
  );
 }
}

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   searchTerm: "",
   counter: 0,
   pastSearches: [],
   data: null
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 }

 componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log("this.state.data", this.state.data);
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  console.log("Mounted");
 }

 handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
  axios
   .get(
    `${BASE_URL}${config.apiKey}${QUERY}${this.state.searchTerm}${LIMITS}`
   )
   .then(result => {
    this.setState({ data: result.data.data });
   });
 }

 render() {
  if (this.state.data) {
   var GIFS = this.state.data.map(d => (
    <GifViewer keyyer={d.embed_url} id={d.id} />
   ));
  }

  return (
   <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row py-5 bg-success">
     <div className="col-8 offset-2">
      <h3 className="text-center">LET'S BREAK THE INTER-WEBZ</h3>
      <input
       type="text"
       className="form-control"
       value={this.state.searchTerm}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       placeholder="Search"
      />
     </div>
    </div>
    {this.state.data ? GIFS : "Nothing yet"}
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can implement Masonry to get a similar effect. More info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component (React implementation of https://masonry.desandro.com/ )

Comment: Not really possible, the part in "inline" that should be emphasized here is _line_. Either go with CSS columns instead ("ordering" would practically be in the orthogonal direction then, if that's acceptable), or you need to go look into something like masonry.js

Comment: Since your images seem to be the same width but varying heights, you can construct your HTML to stack the images vertically rather than horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite way to resolve this is the css property `object-fit: cover;` (applied to your `img` rule).

There's a great article on the property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/), but the gist (for your purpose) is that you can zoom the image to cover the whole space without stretching or distorting the image.